# Listbox fileinfo into another listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have a listbox `lbchannel1` that contains multiple items that are paths like `c:\test` and `c:\temp` for example. Now I want to read all the files (not the content, just the filenames) that are in those folders/paths added to the listbox into another listbox called `lbLog` (or a textbox of that would be better)

The event is on SelectedIndexChanged.

I've tried some versions of this...

```
        Dim f1 As String()
    f1 = Form2.lbchannel1.Items.Cast(Of String).ToArray
    Dim einfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo(f1)
    For Each item As String In f1
       FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, (Form2.tbext1_1.Text))
        lbLog.Items.Add(einfo.Name)
    Next
```

Error: `Value of type 'string()' cannot be converted to 'String'`

But I can't get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Updated my question with the error. I'm pretty sure the code has to be totally different, but for all I know I could be close to a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you all the paths.
Rework it to get just the filenames as required.

```
Private Sub CountFilesButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CountFilesButton.Click
    Try

        For Each item As String In DirListBox.Items
            FilesListBox.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(item.ToString))
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred ", ex.Message))
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Andrew, that was perfect. Thanks a lot! :)